# finding the maxima from a set of local maxima using certain conditions in R

Tags: r, boolean, dplyr

I have a data where I obtained local maxima designated by a `TRUE` value in my `loc_max` column. I would like to identify the "true maxima" from my local maxima based on these conditions: 1.) the 5 values preceding a local maxima must have at least 3 positive first derivative; AND 2.) the succeeding 5 values must have at least 3 negative first derivative. Here's my sample data frame:

```
val <- c(0.06796823, 0.12165540, 0.17685980, 0.28518490, 0.36616820,
        0.40935790, 0.45418170, 0.48220730, 0.45214280, 0.40290130,
        0.38103100, 0.39525690, 0.40527800, 0.48172680, 0.54250300,
        0.56136270, 0.53755350, 0.57047540, 0.55738850, 0.50470080,
        0.47487730, 0.45653140, 0.45670750, 0.43722310, 0.42154800,
        0.41154490, 0.38138090, 0.41802160, 0.42043370, 0.39982040,
        0.35258890, 0.32990900, 0.28508770, 0.23949280, 0.19405640,
        0.16321880, 0.17098540, 0.17572110, 0.17464730, 0.17670690,
        0.16105620, 0.18609890, 0.19083090, 0.19506300, 0.16865580,
        0.15830920)
loc_max <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
             FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
             FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
             FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
             FALSE,  TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
             FALSE)
df <- data.frame(val, loc_max)
```

I was supposed to mutate a new column containing boolean values where my identified "true maxima" will be `TRUE` and the rest will `FALSE`. Thanks in advance for the help.

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
          val loc_max true_max
1  0.06796823   FALSE    FALSE
2  0.12165540   FALSE    FALSE
3  0.17685980   FALSE    FALSE
4  0.28518490   FALSE    FALSE
5  0.36616820   FALSE    FALSE
6  0.40935790   FALSE    FALSE
7  0.45418170   FALSE    FALSE
8  0.48220730    TRUE     TRUE
9  0.45214280   FALSE    FALSE
10 0.40290130   FALSE    FALSE
11 0.38103100   FALSE    FALSE
12 0.39525690   FALSE    FALSE
13 0.40527800   FALSE    FALSE
14 0.48172680   FALSE    FALSE
15 0.54250300   FALSE    FALSE
16 0.56136270    TRUE    FALSE
17 0.53755350   FALSE    FALSE
18 0.57047540    TRUE     TRUE
19 0.55738850   FALSE    FALSE
20 0.50470080   FALSE    FALSE
21 0.47487730   FALSE    FALSE
22 0.45653140   FALSE    FALSE
23 0.45670750    TRUE    FALSE
24 0.43722310   FALSE    FALSE
25 0.42154800   FALSE    FALSE
26 0.41154490   FALSE    FALSE
27 0.38138090   FALSE    FALSE
28 0.41802160   FALSE    FALSE
29 0.42043370    TRUE    FALSE
30 0.39982040   FALSE    FALSE
31 0.35258890   FALSE    FALSE
32 0.32990900   FALSE    FALSE
33 0.28508770   FALSE    FALSE
34 0.23949280   FALSE    FALSE
35 0.19405640   FALSE    FALSE
36 0.16321880   FALSE    FALSE
37 0.17098540   FALSE    FALSE
38 0.17572110    TRUE    FALSE
39 0.17464730   FALSE    FALSE
40 0.17670690    TRUE    FALSE
41 0.16105620   FALSE    FALSE
42 0.18609890   FALSE    FALSE
43 0.19083090   FALSE    FALSE
44 0.19506300    TRUE    FALSE
45 0.16865580   FALSE    FALSE
46 0.15830920   FALSE    FALSE
```

I'm including this plot for clarity:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean ***both** the 5 values preceding and the 5 values succeeding* should contain at least 3 `FALSE` values *each* of the preceding and of the succeding? Or is it: there is a `TRUE` and give or take 2 vector elements from that one (5 in total) there should be at least 3 `FALSE`?

Comment: r u simply looking for `replace(logical(nrow(df)), which.max(df$val), TRUE)`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Nope. That only gives the maxima.

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic I think my original question was unclear. I restated it above. Thanks!

Comment: @RonakShah restated my question and updated expected results as suggested

Comment: What do you mean by `3 positive first derivative;` and `3 negative first derivative. ` ?

Comment: @RonakShah i think he meant diff(df$val) > 0 before the "true max" and diff(df$val) < 0 after the "true max" but still not clear why he choose 18 and no row 16, 23 and 29

Comment: My posted solution matches @chinsoon12's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution following the problem's description but the output does not match the posted output.

```
truemax <- function(i, X){
  j <- (i - 5):i
  j <- j[j >= 1]
  d <- diff(X$val[j])
  pos <- sum(d > 0) >= 3
  j <- i:(i + 5)
  j <- j[j <= nrow(X)]
  d <- diff(X$val[j])
  neg <- sum(d < 0) >= 3
  pos && neg
}

df$true_max <- FALSE
for(i in which(df$loc_max)){
  df$true_max[i] <- truemax(i, df)
}
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified Rui's solution and added another condition, which is to make sure that the 3 values that precedes and succeeds `true_max` must be positive.

```
truemax <- function(i, X){ #try i=16
  j <- (i - 5):(i-1)
  j <- j[j >= 1]
  d <- diff(X$val[j])
  pos <- ifelse(sum(d > 0) >= 3 & mean(X$val[j[3:5]] <= X$val[i]) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
  j <- i:(i + 5)
  j <- j[j <= nrow(X)]
  d <- diff(X$val[j])
  neg <- ifelse(sum(d < 0) >= 3 & mean(X$val[j[2:4]] <= X$val[i]) == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
  pos && neg
}

df$true_max <- FALSE
for(i in which(df$loc_max)){
  df$true_max[i] <- truemax(i, df)
}
df
```